# Android Facebook SDK 3.0 Read Notifications

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm having an issue with the Facebook graph API not returning anything for a request to get a user's notifications. I'm doing it through a batch request, using the same syntax to get a user's news feed, and the news feed request works fine. I have the "manage_notifications" permission enabled also. I always get a null pointer exception in my code when I try to parse the result of the graph call to notifications.

Note that when I got to the graph explorer in my internet browser and type "me/notifications?include_read=true" I DO get the appropriate data.

Here's the code for my request.

```
static Request notificationsRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(fbSession, "me/notifications?include_read=true", new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        GraphObject object = response.getGraphObject();
        if(object != null){
            notifications = object.getProperty("data").toString();
        }
        else{
            notifications = "Notifications returns null";
        }

    }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I updated the code and found out that the GraphObject object is returning null and that's why it can't parse anything from it. It seems like there would be something wrong with the graph request, but I can't figure out what it is. Like I said, the exact same method for getting a user's news feed ("me/home") works perfectly fine.

Comment: Why dont you just use getGraphObject()?

Comment: I got rid of the .getInnerJSONObject() and it didn't give me an error any more. Let me try to see if I can get the "data" array from that.

Comment: I updated the code and found that the GraphObject object is returning null. I'll update the post.

Comment: Try to use fql for that query then. It may be more helpful!

Comment: That was plan B. I've been trying to do everything with graph calls, but I guess I'll give FQL a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of passing the parameter in the Graph path, add it as a parameter to the request:

me/notifications?include_read=true

```
static Request notificationsRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(fbSession, "me/notifications", new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        GraphObject object = response.getGraphObject();
        if(object != null){
            notifications = object.getProperty("data").toString();
        }
        else{
            notifications = "Notifications returns null";
        }

    }
});


Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("include_read", "true");

notificationsRequest.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got it to work using FQL, so I'll try to give this a go when I get back to working on notifications. FWIW I was using "me/notifications?include_read=true" as my graph path. Does adding the "include_read=true" condition through a bundle do something different than explicitly declaring it in the graph path?

Comment: I've seen feedback that it may actually get dropped when added in the graph path.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way. I will post it in case somebody finds it helpful

```
    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        InboxMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        new Request(session,"/me/notifications", null,HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback() {

                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        GraphObject object = response.getGraphObject();
                            if (object != null) {
                                InboxMessage.setText(object.getProperty("data").toString());
                            } else {
                                InboxMessage.setText("Notifications returns null");
                            }
                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();
    } else {
        InboxMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}
```